# 'LdaMulticore' object has no attribute 'minimum_probability'?

Tags: lda, gensim

It is my first time to use gensim package to run LDA model, and the problem happened as followed:

I had train and save lda model to the local file 'lda.model' last night,   and when I try to usinfer topic distributions on new, unseen documents, with run() funciton:

```
self.lda = models.LdaMulticore.load('./lda_model/lda.model')
print self.lda[self.corpus_tfidf]
```

then Error happend!

```
AttributeError: 'LdaMulticore' object has no attribute 'minimum_probability'
```

The following is my source code,Could you help me?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#@author: chenbjin
#@time:  2015-08-3
import jieba, os, logging
from base_func import *
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities

class LDAModel(object):
    """docstring for LDAModel"""
    def __init__(self, train_data='./data/train_set.txt'):
        super(LDAModel, self).__init__()
        self.dic = None
        self.corpus = None
        self.tfidf_model = None
        self.corpus_tfidf = None
        self.lda_model = None
        self.train_set = load_train_set(train_data)
        self.test_set = None

    def train(self):
        self.dic = corpora.Dictionary(self.train_set)
        self.corpus = [ self.dic.doc2bow(text) for text in self.train_set ]
        self.tfidf_model = models.TfidfModel.load('./tfidf_model/tfidf.model')
        #self.tfidf_model = models.TfidfModel(self.corpus)
        #self.tfidf_model.save('./tfidf_model/tfidf.model')
        self.corpus_tfidf = self.tfidf_model[self.corpus]

        self.lda_model = models.LdaMulticore(self.corpus_tfidf, id2word = self.dic, num_topics = 50)
        self.lda_model.save('./lda_model/lda.model')

    def run(self, test_set='./data/test_set.txt'):
        self.test_set = load_train_set(test_set)
        self.dic = corpora.Dictionary(self.test_set)
        self.corpus = [ self.dic.doc2bow(text) for text in self.test_set ]

        self.tfidf_model = models.TfidfModel.load('./tfidf_model/tfidf.model')
        self.corpus_tfidf = self.tfidf_model[self.corpus]

        self.lda = models.LdaMulticore.load('./lda_model/lda.model')
        print self.lda[self.corpus_tfidf]


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

    lda = LDAModel(train_data=None)
    lda.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```